# How to serialize full list instead of row by row

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, data-binding

My `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataSource` defined here:

```
BindingList<CompanyProfile> DataSource = new BindingList<CompanyProfile>();
```

where `CompanyProfile` class is:

```
public class CompanyProfile
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; } 
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string IMO { get; set; } = "Some Value";
}
```

Now I want to take the entire DataSource and write an XML file containing all the items. Before, I tried this serialization:

```
// Iterate the datasource list, not the DataGridView.
foreach (CompanyProfile companyProfile in DataSource)
{
    CreateClientFile(
        companyProfile,
        fileName: Path.Combine(appData,
        $"{companyProfile.CompanyName}_{companyProfile.SiteName}.xml")
    );
}
```

where `CreateClientFile` uses XmlSerializer:

```
private void CreateClientFile(CompanyProfile companyProfile, string fileName)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(CompanyProfile));
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        x.Serialize(writer, companyProfile);
    }
    // Open the file to view the result
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", fileName);
}
```

but I end up with a file for every record. How can I serialize my DataSource so that it makes *one* file with *all* the CompanyProfile records in it?

I really want to learn and grasp this concept, staarted reading about Serilization and Databinding as suggested but I get stuck.

I hope someone is willing to help me a bit further

Comment: Is your `DataSource` a `DataTable`? If so, it has the [DataTable.WriteXml Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml?view=net-6.0) and its counterpart [DataTable.ReadXml Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.readxml?view=net-6.0)

Comment: I believe it is a "dataGridView" or am I confusing things here?

Comment: DataGridView should be your UI Component. It has a DataSource, which you set as `dataGridView1.DataSource = this.DataSource;`. What type is `this.DataSource`?

Comment: Usually a well formed xml file has only one root tag.  Then has arrays at child element.  The solution is to create a root and then put the the rows under one root.

Comment: In that case I think (I'm sorry but I try to learn this) it is a BindingList

BindingList<MachineProfile> DataSource = new BindingList<MachineProfile>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will elaborate on the excellent comment by jdweng.

In the code you posted, you go through your `DataSource` and use `XmlSerializer` for each record. But, to achieve the outcome you want, where the `DataSource` writes a single file and has all of the records, you need to change your definition of the serializer:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(BindingList<CompanyProfile>), 
    new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
```

The other change is easy, because you take your `btnSerialize_Click` method and  serialize the **entire List** with the `x.Serialize(writer, DataSource)` line.

```
private void btnSerialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = Path.Combine(
        appData,
        "CompanyProfiles.xml");

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        x.Serialize(writer, DataSource);
    }
    Process.Start("notepad.exe", fileName);
}
```

Your file now has the correct document structure because there is a `root` node. The data for the two `CompanyProfile` records comes under the `root` node:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CompanyProfile>
    <CompanyName>Linear Technology</CompanyName>
    <SiteName>Colorado Design Center</SiteName>
    <IMO>Some Value</IMO>
  </CompanyProfile>
  <CompanyProfile>
    <CompanyName>Analog Devices</CompanyName>
    <SiteName>1-1-2</SiteName>
    <IMO>Some Value</IMO>
  </CompanyProfile>
</root>
```

I hope this will assist you in your goal of learning more about serialization.

Comment: Ill have it a try tomorrow. thanks a lot for all the patience and good advice!